# Facebook Authentication c# integration using Facebook login buttons

Tags: c#, facebook

I have created an application that logs in and registers via a button click.  This all works as expected by using the access token in the code behind to process the login and gain users details for prefilling some forms.

The customer has now asked for something similar to the facebook login button that puts the login/ application authentication in like a frame, rather than redirecting the user to facebook.

Looking at the documentation I am a bit puzzled on how to do this.  Do the facebook login/authentication javascript buttons provide an access code for manipulation in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a popup login using the Facebook javascript SDK like so:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'auth.login',
    perms: 'publish_stream',
    display: 'popup' },
    function (rsp) {
        fg_log('on login');                             
        if(rsp.session) { 
            if(rsp.perms) {

            } else {

            }
        } else {
            fg_log('No login');
        }
    }
);
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The Social Plugins are self contained, and do everything client-side. You can however hook the [login/logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) events in the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and use AJAX to talk to the server. You can also get the Facebook auth cookie server-side on subsequent requests to see if the user is logged in, which can also be validated.

Take a look [Integration of Facebook and asp.net membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289480/integration-of-facebook-and-asp-net-membership), for an example of setting up .Net authentication with Facebook access_token.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach that I took for my own projects are:

- use facebook javascript SDK to do user login.
- after login is successful, user will be able to grand their
  access_token
- Pass that access_token in your postback page query string (or anything suits you)
- by using Graph API with Access_token from code behind you will be
  able to grab user info from facebook.
- then you will able to compare user info between your own user
  provider and set that user as logged in

Comment: This is very much what I wanted to hear, I have been looking at the JavaScript SDK, and can see how you access the user's information but cannot see where you can obtain the Access_token